# signalR-1.0.0-rc2 User Identity not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I was trying to use signalR 1.0.0 RC2, as I noticed quite a lot of things have been changed since 0.5.3, one thing that is not working is "**Context.User.Identity.Name**", which gives me null value, I'm not sure,is that still the right way to access windows user identity?

```
  [HubName("chatroom")]
 public class ChatRoomHub : Hub
 {
    public void Join()
    {
      User newUser = new User();

      newUser.ClientID = Context.ConnectionId;
      newUser.Login = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
      newUser.Content = " joined discussion";
      newUser.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

      this.Clients.Join(newUser);
    }       
  } 

string name = Context.User.Identity.Name; // name is blank here
```

In 1.0.0 RC2, Context.User.Identity.Name is null

Comment: Can you be more specific. Are you on self host or asp.net? What are you doing?

Comment: in asp.net, this approach was working in 0.5.3

Comment: And it should still work fine in ASP.NET on rc2.

Comment: `public override Task OnConnected()
    {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name; // name is blank here.
            return Clients.All.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }`

Comment: File a bug and attach the repro project.

Comment: Find out it's not an issue about SignalR.
When hosting on the server using IIS or Use Visual Studio Development Server option, there is no issue at all.
But when using Local IIS Web server option in VS, the user identity is blank. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In my project this solved the problem:

(File: Web.config)

```
<system.web> 
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Find out it's not an issue about SignalR. When hosting on the server using IIS or Use Visual Studio Development Server option, there is no issue at all. But when using Local IIS Web server option in VS, the user identity is blank. Thanks for the reply.